# bitcoin-cli -netinfo not showing incoming ipv4 peers

Tags: network, peers, connection

I was trying to get my bitcoin node to be able to receive ipv4 peers for couple of days, but could not see any incoming peers even tho my port 8333 was open and reachable and to my best knowledge bitcoin.conf is correct.
Today I have spin up another node and used addnode=mainnodeip to see whether I can connect to my main node. Connection out went fine, data is being received, but still in bitcoin-cli -netinfo of my main node I don't see this connection.Is this a bug?
I can see the outbound connection on my testing node, but not inbound in my main node.

Thank you for any tips or explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably connected to your other node over the local network? In that case, this issue has just been corrected in the master branch a couple of weeks ago (https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/26584) - so that this should be fixed with the next 25.0 release.

In the meantime, you could use `bitcoin-cli getpeerinfo` as an alternative, which doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Thank you foe help. It was not on a local network, but I did try 'bitcoin-cli getpeerinfo' to examine the peers close. I can see quite a few inbound peer which have "network": "not_publicly_routable" which seem odd to me. What would this mean?

Comment: That means that bitcoin core thinks that the address (field "addr" in getpeerinfo) with which they connect to you is not publicly routable on the internet.